# Summarize grouping by year and month

Tags: google-sheets

I have a worksheet *Movements* with two fields:

```
mydate      | amount
2009-01-01  | 10.00
2009-01-02  | 13.00
2009-02-01  | 11.00
2009-02-05  | 12.00
2009-02-08  | 52.00
```

I want to have in another worksheet *MonthSum* that displays the sums of the data in the column *amount* grouped by year+month of the column *date*:

```
mydate      | amount
2009-01     | 23.00
2009-02     | 75.00
```

I don't want to specify the cells where the spreadsheet has to sum, I want a generic formula to group my data per month+year. If I was on a MySQL database I would simply do:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m', mydate), SUM(amount) 
FROM mytable GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m', mydate)
```

I need the solution to work on **Google Spreadsheets**.

I think that possible solutions would be using SUMIF or pivot tables or Google Spreadsheets QUERY [function](https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=1388882).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do it with an array formula, i put the formula in `A2` and in `A1`, i put the month number:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(1*(MONTH(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6)=A1)*Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6))
```

See the [doc in action in Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Avv4SM5QSNYtdHlUU3E0REFMMVdjVFpQeUkwOVVZRWc&hl=en_GB)

[EDIT] If you want both year and month:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(1*(YEAR(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$8)=A2)*(MONTH(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$8)=B2)*Sheet1!$B$2:$B$8))
```

Comment: I want the *amount* column group by year+month, not just month

Comment: @ashes999: I suggest you ask a new question and add a link to this answer so that you will get a broader audience and probably more answers

Comment: @TilmanVogel: I've checked the link and it seems to work wether I am logged in or not.

Comment: @JMax not here (I am logged in): Sheet 1 has the date in French and Sheet 2 gives "#VALUE" errors in column C.

Comment: @TilmanVogel: ok, got it. I've corrected my formulas (and data), sorry for the #VALUE

Answer (score 95):

This is what *pivot tables* are for.

I have created [an example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At5oc_kwXKsmdGVXV3liejliTGM2alpZZjh5aktuYUE) using your data.

### First, add a column to format the date as your monthly string, eg "2009-01" with the formula:

`TEXT(A2, "YYYY-MM")`

[image]

---

### Then highlight the data, and choose "data" > "pivot table report..."

[image]

---

### For Rows, select "month"

[image]

---

### For Values, select "amount"

[image]

---

### TADA! That's it!

[image]

For a quick overview of pivot tables, see [this Google blog post](https://drive.googleblog.com/2011/05/summarize-your-data-with-pivot-tables.html).

Comment: It's exactly what I want, and an easy one.

Comment: Fair enough @pnuts , thanks for the edit. It's probably just a retina screen thing that meant I had high resolution screenshots ;)

Comment: Pro tip: if the source data is going to grow, edit the range from `Sheet1!A1:C6` to just refer to the data by columns: `Sheet1!A:C`

Comment: Great answer using pivot tables instead of weird formulas. Just used it.

Answer (score 16):

in addition to contribution from JMax,
let me present the following formula using the QUERY function ...

```sql
=query(index('Sheet3'!A:B); "select year(Col1)+(month(Col1)+1)/100,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by year(Col1)+(month(Col1)+1)/100 label year(Col1)+(month(Col1)+1)/100 'mydate',sum(Col2) 'amount' ")
```

Notes:
I have assumed the original data is in Sheet3
and my result presents the year and month combinationas yyyy.mm instead of yyyy-mm
I have created an illustration:

[image: yogi]

Comment: Interesting, but then you have october displaying "2020.1" instead of "2020.10"

Answer (score 2):

The answer of matt burns and Cœur is pretty accurate and I would like to add a comment (I did not add it on the comment section as it is quite long)

You may want to use this formula instead:
`DATE(YEAR(A2);MONTH(A2);1)` to group by year & month.

This way you **will keep values as dates** and therefore be able to apply any kind of **date formatting** or sorting in your pivot table.

---

Explanation you can skip:

Instead of `TEXT(A2, "YYYY-MM")` converts value in text and therefore remove freedom about further date manipulation.

`DATE(YEAR(A2);MONTH(A2);1)` remove the day and time from the date so for example *2018/05/03* and *2018/05/06* both become *2018/05/01* which is still a date which can then be grouped together.

By applying a format "YYYY-MM" directly on the pivot table you reach the same result.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an array approach. How to combine arrays you can learn here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42488671/1393023

### Foremost `QUERY`

It's simple and transparent

```
=QUERY(
  ARRAYFORMULA({TEXT(Movements!A:A,"YYYY-MM"),Movements!B:B}),
  "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1"
)
```

### Secondly `ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF)`

Just combine the functions to a chain

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(
  {
    TEXT(Movements!A2:A,"YYYY-MM"),
    SUMIF(EOMONTH(Movements!A2:A,1),EOMONTH(Movements!A2:A,1),Movements!B2:B)
  },
  LEN(Movements!B2:B)
)),1,1)
```

[My example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NB9aXQSUnxxpBNXOCx6xp1mOqpQDj-2QQk8ULhn3Vog/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I was working with a similar issue. I found this formula to work well.

```
=SUMIF(ARRAYFORMULA(MONTH('Sheet1'!A:A)), A2, 'Sheet1'!B:B)
```

In cell `A2` I put the month I wanted totaled.