# Use date as a criteria in SUM or sumif function

Tags: excel, sum

I have two columns

```
Amount    Date

100       01/01/2000  
2000      01/12/2002
2000      02/02/2005
150       03/02/2000
250       05/03/2002
350       04/05/2006
```

I need result as follows

```
Total year 

2005 - 2000
2000 - 250
2002 - 2250
2006 - 350
```

Can I use SUMIF function for this? If it's possible what criteria I have to put?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same formula as described in this thread: [Summarize grouping by year and month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313580/google-spreadsheet-summarize-grouping-by-year-and-month/)

```
=SUMPRODUCT((YEAR(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$6)=A2)*Sheet1!$A$2:$A$6)
```

I supposed your data are in an array from `A1` to `A6` on `Sheet1` and your results are on another Sheet, you put the year in `column A` and the formula in `column B`

Answer (score 0):

If you add a column to the right of the date column containing

```
=year(B2)
```

(replace B2 with whichever cell contains the date in that row)
and fill that column down, then you can do a standard sumif on that column like

```
=sumif(C2:C10, 2002, A2:A10)
```