# How to union ranges in google spreadsheets

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to union ranges from any Google spreadsheets.

### The example

*Sheet1!A:A*

```
{12, 131, 45}
```

*Sheet2!A:A*

```
{12, 131, 46}
```

*The unknown function*

```
=formula_for_union_range(Sheet1!A:A; Sheet2!:A:A)
```

*should return*

```
{12, 131, 45, 12, 131, 46}
```

### The question

How is it possible?

Comment: The answer is in the [Google Sheets docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en-GB&ref_topic=9055396)

Comment: @Lloyd, ten years ago, this article did not exist. Did I in a hurry to ask?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

## Google Apps Script

And yet the question was about the script. I'm still successfully using the following code:

```
function unionRanges(e) {
  var result = [];
  var length = 0;
  var i = 0;
  try {
    for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
      length += arguments[i].length;
    if (length > 3000) return '#BIGRANGE';
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
      result = result.concat(arguments[i].filter(function (el) {
        return el.join('').length > 0
      }));
    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    return JSON.stringify(err);
  }
}
```

## Spreadsheets feature

But, as noted above, it is easier to use `{}`-notation.

```
={ Sheet1!A1:C10 ; Sheet2!A1:C34 }
```

Vertical concatenation

```
={ Range(Cols=N) ; Range(Cols=N) }
```

Horizontal concatenation

```
={ Range(Rows=M) , Range(Rows=M) }
```

It's possible to combine

```
={ { , , } ; { , , } }
```

Or something more hard

```
={{{;;},{;;}};{{;;},{;;}};{{;;},{;;}}}
```

Try something like this

```
={
   {{ 1; 2; 3},{ 4; 5; 6}};
   {{ 7; 8; 9},{10;11;12}};
   {{13;14;15},{16;17;18}}
 }
```

The internal horizontal concatenation is not required

```
={
    { 1; 2; 3},{ 4; 5; 6};
    { 7; 8; 9},{10;11;12};
    {13;14;15},{16;17;18}
}
```

### Locale dependencies of argument delimiters

If your current locale supports `,` as an argument delimiter thnen you should use `;` for a vertical concatenation and `,` for a horizontal concatenation.

Otherwise your argument delimiter is `;` and you have to use `;` and `\` (without spaces), respectively.

#### Sheet `'Data 1'!A1:C20`

```
|   Name  |    Date   | Sum |
| Ethan   |  3/4/2017 |  31 |
| Logan   |  3/6/2017 |  62 |
| Brian   | 3/26/2017 |  61 |
|   ...   |     ...   | ... |
```

#### Sheet `'Data 2'!A1:C20`

```
|  Name   |    Date   | Sum |
| Nathan  | 3/30/2017 |  53 |
| Alyssa  | 3/13/2017 |  72 |
| John    | 3/24/2017 |  79 |
| Megan   | 3/16/2017 |  10 |
|   ...   |     ...   | ... |
```

### Concatenation

#### Vertical concatenation

```
={'Data 1'!A1:C20;'Data 2'!A2:C20}
```

##### Result

```
|  Name  |    Date   | Sum |
| Ethan  |  3/4/2017 |  31 |
| Logan  |  3/6/2017 |  62 |
| Brian  | 3/26/2017 |  61 |
| ...    |       ... | ... |
| Nathan | 3/30/2017 |  53 |
| Alyssa | 3/13/2017 |  72 |
| John   | 3/24/2017 |  79 |
| ...    |       ... | ... |
```

#### Horizontal concatenation

```
={TRANSPOSE('Data 1'!A1:C20),TRANSPOSE('Data 2'!A2:C20)}
```

##### Result

```
| Name |   Ethan  |   Logan  |   Brian   | ... |   Nathan  |   Alyssa  |    John   |
| Date | 3/4/2017 | 3/6/2017 | 3/26/2017 | ... | 3/30/2017 | 3/13/2017 | 3/24/2017 |
| Sum  |       31 |       62 |        61 | ... |        53 |        72 |        79 |
```

More about this [How to concatenate ranges in Google spreadsheets](https://gist.github.com/contributorpw/70759205b0f28faacfe0def50e7b66dc)

Comment: Note, on vertical concatenation, the `;` are important; it doesn't work for `,` as it puts ranges horizontally without transposing them.

Comment: Why is 3000 returns BIGRANGE ? What happens if we have 10k or 100k results?

Comment: @SébCô, it's just a sample. Setup this as you want.

Answer (score 172):

Just use:

```
={sheet1!a:a; sheet2!a:a}
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer. Amazingly, using a union this way even works with named ranges, ranges with more than one column, and a VLOOKUP formula.

Comment: In passing:  You don't seem to be able to matrix syntax in named ranges.  E.g. you cannot define a named range with disjoint cells.

Comment: Amazing. Works with named ranges too `={mon20190722T200000;mon20190729T200000;mon20190805T200000;mon20190812T200000}`

Comment: Just adding a note that if you're using `Query()`, this changes the column names to 'Col1', 'Col2' etc

Comment: Note: if any of the ranges are "empty". It'll insert a blank item. I used a query to remove all blank items.  =IFERROR(QUERY({sheet1!a:a; sheet2!a:a}, "SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1<>''"), "") . This will at least only have a blank entry if the query results are completely empty

Answer (score 110):

You can merge them into 1 column then get the unique values. **Check the following formula:**

```
=UNIQUE({Sheet1!A:A;Sheet2!A:A})
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer has fewer votes than the accepted one from Henrique. This seems to be right way to do it - with pure matrix notation - while the other answer seems to have completely unnecessary textual split/join commands which will slow things down a lot, and blow up if the involved cells have commas or semi-colons.

Comment: If you have multiple columns - why does it put next to each other? I used it to pull three columns from three sheets and it didn't join them just put them one next to the other?

Comment: OP did not want unique values (`{12, 131, 45, 12, 131, 46}`)

Comment: @Moseleyi: You probably did the same thing I did: use a comma instead of a semicolon. With comma, you get three columns. With semicolon, the ranges are unioned.

Comment: OP isn't asking for duplicate removal.

Comment: Google sheets removes semi-colons and replaces with commas!

Comment: Duplicate removal is necessary. It is part of the definition of "union"

Answer (score 21):

Although a script can do this easily, I recommend using regular spreadsheet formulas, e.g.

```
=transpose(split(join(";";Sheet1!A:A)&";"&join(";";Sheet2!A:A);";"))
```

To remove duplicates, just wrap it in a `unique` formula:

```
=unique(transpose(...))
```

And to sort... `=sort(...)`

Comment: This is weird. Joining cells into a big string just to split it up is not very efficient. See below for better answers.

Comment: Yep, wrapping up the ranges in an array is a nice trick too. More importantly, it looks more clear. But worrying about formula performance in a spreadsheet is kinda funny.

Comment: There's a limit of 50000 characters in a string function like SPLIT or JOIN. So it only works with small or simple dataset.

Answer (score 4):

At first when I tried `={Sheet1!A:A; Sheet2!A:A}`, I thought it didn't work because I could only see results from the first sheet. Turned out it was including all the blank cells too!

To filter out blank and empty cells while preserving duplicates (unlike `=UNIQUE`) and without repeating yourself (unlike `=FILTER()`), you can use  [`=QUERY()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en), like so:

```
=QUERY(
  {March!A1:Z; April!A2:Z; May!A2:Z}, 
  "select * where Col1 != '' and Col1 is not null", 
  0)
```

(Note that I am including the header row from the first sheet, and omitting it from the other sheets).

If your sheets don't contain cells with empty text, you can omit `Col1 != '' and`.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have:

```
   A    B   C   D   E   F
1: 1    2   3   4   5   6
```

It's possible to concatenate slices as either rows or columns.

For additional columns (same row), use a comma. `={$A1:$C1,$D1:$F1}` yields:

```
1   2   3   4   5   6
```

For additional rows (same columns), use a semicolon. `={$A1:$C1;$D1:$F1}` yields:

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
```

Comment: +1 for the tip on comma vs semicolon. Also if your comma separator is the comma character (Spain for instance), the union character for columns is \ instead of coma

Answer (score 1):

If you want to union sheets and exclude rows with empty cells use the [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) function in your formula:

```
=FILTER({Sheet1!A:A;Sheet2!A:A}, {Sheet1!A:A;Sheet2!A:A}<>"")
```