# How to combine two disjoint ranges in an array formula

Tags: excel

How can I combine two disjoint ranges to be used in an array formula.

Example:

```
{=PERCENTILE(10^((E2:F2)/10),0.7)}
```

This works however:

```
{=PERCENTILE(10^((E2:F2,N2:P2)/10),0.7)}
```

This will fail.
How can I get this functionality to work in excel?

Comment: It's seeming like your exponentiation is where this breaks down. You can do exponentiation in an array formula, but not with disjointed ranges.

Comment: Yes I can do it with a continuous range but not a disjoint range.  I would like to know how I can achieve this with a disjoint range

Comment: worth doing a UDF for the whole first parameter expression maybe...

Comment: How would I do a UDF.  I tried a union but that did not seem to work

Comment: For other Googlers, seems like the [comma operator is the right answer when it works (which is not always unfortunately)](https://superuser.com/a/447560/10136), and unlike [Google sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10793321/1026), Excel [doesn't allow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46002409/1026) to construct arrays from cell references (i.e. `SUM({E2:F2,N2:P2})`)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but since this is what comes up in Google searches for disjoint ranges:   newer excel versions support joining disjoint ranges using colon:

```
{=PERCENTILE(10^((E2:F2:N2:P2)/10),0.7)
```

You can add a colon and another start:end style range, as many times as you want.