# Is it possible to use individual cell references in an Excel array within a function?

Tags: arrays, excel

I have some data I want to put into the LOGEST() function

```
(e.g. x values =0.463, 0.609, 0.887, y values = 0.05, 0.1, 0.2 )
```

For this example I have put the data into these columns:
[image]
Both these formula work (return the correct value of 0.665...):

```
= INDEX( LOGEST({0.95;0.9;0.8}, {0.463;0.609;0.887}, TRUE, FALSE), 1)
```

and

```
= INDEX( LOGEST( B2:B4, A2:A4, TRUE, FALSE), 1)
```

But I cannot get the formula to call individual cells in the array.
I have tried a few things e.g.

```
= INDEX( LOGEST({0.95,0.9,0.8}, {"A2","A3","A4"}, TRUE, FALSE), 1)
= INDEX( LOGEST({0.95,0.9,0.8}, (A2, A3, A4), TRUE, FALSE), 1)
```

And some other variations, but I cannot get excel to treat individual cell values as array values.
Is there a way to do this or is the only constant cell referencing possible the A2:A4? I ask because in my real data I can't use this range function as my data is not distributed in that form (there are gaps). (Note: In case it is relevant ultimately I don't want the cell values to remain fixed - they should move downwards when I drag expand downwards).

Comment: Just use `A2:A4` no `()` or `{}`

Comment: So the first array (for known_ys) is always to be entered as a static, in-formula array constant and it is only the second array (for known_xs) which needs to reference actual cell addresses?

Comment: In my actual data yes the ys will be constant and the xs will change. I would be interested to know how to do this for either though. @XORLX

Comment: Does this help: https://excelxor.com/2016/02/16/criteria-with-statistical-functions-growth-linest-logest-trend/?

Comment: Some functions will not accept discontinuous ranges as arguments.  But you can write a UDF that can create an array constant from a discontinuous range.

Comment: Note that it may also be possible to construct an array without VBA using the approach suggested by @XORLX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the CHOOSE function to return the array...

```
= INDEX( LOGEST({0.95;0.9;0.8}, CHOOSE({1;2;3},A2,A3,A4), TRUE, FALSE), 1)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: True, but if the OP has in reality not three but several dozen (or even hundred) cells to consider the above becomes a little unwieldy, not to mention difficult to update should those cells change.

Comment: Thank you @Domenic this is exactly the correct function!

Comment: @XOR LX Yeah, in that case, another approach would be necessary.