# How do I combine arrays from multiple pages in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data from 3 separate google forms on 3 different pages and would like to have all of these arrays combined into one on a different page. These forms are ongoing so the arrays will individually keep growing hence why I can't just do 3 array formula's one beneath the other.

Is there an inbuilt function already within google sheets that can achieve this?

All evidence I can find for doing this is using the concat or textjoin functions where data is taken from a few boxes and essentially combined into one cell. This is not what I want

Array formulas can only take one input so I can't do =arrayformula(Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3)

Comment: Use filter function for 3 different sheet then combine them using array stacking `{....}`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to union ranges in google spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10793321/how-to-union-ranges-in-google-spreadsheets)

Comment: Refer  **this** answer: [How to union ranges in google spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67863935/1330560)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A1:C;Sheet2!A2:C;Sheet3!A2:C},"where Col1 is not null")
```

You just have to adjust the ranges.