# Sum by Month & Year: Query in Google Sheets and how to ignore blank cells?

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets

Sum by Month & Year: Query in Google Sheets

The date format in S1 is `mm/dd/yy`
Attempting to sum the values in `‘S1’!F`

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313580/summarize-grouping-by-year-and-month) and contributorpw’s method was spot on. However, I don’t know how to exclude blank cells in `col A`.

I know with QUERY: “`…where A is not null`” but got error message with:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({TEXT('S1'!A:A,"YYYY-MM"),'S1'!F:F}),"select Col1,sum(Col2) where A is not null group by Col1")
```

And this still returned values for blank cells in ‘S1’!A:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({TEXT('S1'!A:A,"YYYY-MM"),'S1'!F:F}),"select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1")
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=query({index(if(len('S1'!A2:A),eomonth('S1'!A2:A,),)),'S1'!F2:F},"select Col1,sum(Col2) Where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2) '' format Col1 'mmm-YY'")
```

[image]