# Google Sheets: Find all values between two variable date ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets form that looks like the following

| Description | Start date | End Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 01-01-2023 | 01-01-2025 | 30 |
| Second | 01-01-2024 | 01-06-2024 | 10 |
| Third | 01-02-2024 | 01-01-2025 | 15 |
| Fourth | 01-08-2024 | 01-12-2025 | 20 |

And another that looks like:

| Month | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 01-2024 | *TOTAL* (expected = 40) |
| 02-2024 | *TOTAL* (expected = 55) |

etc..

I want to calculate the totals of all that are in the first month in 2024, etc.
I've looked into the `=SUMIFS` function, but cant figure it out correctly.

How can I archive this?

Comment: Would you please edit your question to include the outcome of a successful calculation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum by Month & Year: Query in Google Sheets and how to ignore blank cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76358522/sum-by-month-year-query-in-google-sheets-and-how-to-ignore-blank-cells)

Comment: No that does not answer my question @Tedinoz I need to have all values that are between a certain date range. The startdate and enddate in the first table. I updated the question with expected answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=sumifs(D:D,B:B,"<="&F2,C:C,">"&F2)
```

- *for `Feb'24` the formula_output is coming out as `65` while your expected_value is `55`?!*

[image]

Comment: You are correct, I made a mistake in the expectation. But your formula is working, thanks!